# Router and DS model with belongsTo throws confusing exception

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My router keeps throwing the following exception:

```
Error while processing route: report Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'location' record to this relationship Error: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'location' record to this relationship
```

DS models:

```
App.Location = DS.Model.extend({
    street: DS.attr('string'),
    city: DS.attr('string'),
    area: DS.attr('string'),
    lat: DS.attr('string'),
    lng: DS.attr('string'),
    report: DS.belongsTo('report', {embedded: 'load'})
});

App.Report = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    reg_num: DS.attr('string'),
    location_str: DS.attr('string'),
    location: DS.belongsTo('location', {embedded: 'load'})
});
```

and my router:

```
App.ReportRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.createRecord('report', {
            title: '',
            description: '',
            reg_num: '',
            location_str: '',
            location: {
                street: '',
                city: '',
                area: '',
                lat: '',
                lng: ''
            }
        });
    },
    setupController : function(controller, model){
        controller.set("model", model);
    }
});
```

In the above code I use `location` as the record which belongs to `report`.

The interesting thing is that if I change `location` to `Location` in App.Report:

```
Location: DS.belongsTo('location', {embedded: 'load'})
```

The error disappears. Why? I'm still defining the `location` property inside `report` in my router, I expected the same error.

The problem with `Location` is that it appears with capital letter in the request:

```
{
    "report": {
        "title":"asd",
        "description":"asdasd",
        "reg_num":"",
        "location_str":"novi sad",
        "Location":null
    }
}
```

How to set up the models to get `location` in the request sent to the server?

**EDIT**

Model saving:

```
App.ReportController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        saveReport: function(record) {
            if (!this.get('title')) {
                alert('Title is empty');
            } else {
                var self = this,
                    report = this.store.createRecord('report', {
                        title: this.get('title'),
                        description: this.get('description'),
                        reg_num: this.get('reg_num'),
                        location_str: this.get('location_str'),
                        location: this.store.createRecord('location', {
                            street: this.get('street'),
                            city: this.get('city'),
                            area: this.get('area'),
                            lat: this.get('lat'),
                            lng: this.get('lng')
                        })
                    });
                console.log(report);
                report.save().then(function (result) {
                    self.transitionToRoute('list');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is because in your report route model hook, you're setting the location property on the report record to a JavaScript object literal instead of an ember data model.

You would need to do something like this instead:

```
model: function () {
  return this.store.createRecord('report', {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    reg_num: '',
    location_str: '',
    location: this.store.createRecord('location', {
      street: '',
      city: '',
      area: '',
      lat: '',
      lng: ''
    }),
  });
},
```

The error goes away when you change it to "Location" because it's no longer trying to use the object as an ember data model.

As far as how to get ember data to use the capitalized Location key, you could create a serializer for the report model and override the [normalizePayload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelSerializer.html#method_normalizePayload) hook to transform the location key.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out as soon as I can report back.

Comment: Is this equivalent with creating a report and a location object in the store and later saying: `report.set('location', location)`?

Comment: Okay, this code only helps to bypass the exception, the request sent to the server now contains `location` but it's always `undefined`.

Comment: Any suggestions on this, am I missing something trivial?